# Android/Java - Out of Memory Exception with Dream Service

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have developed an application that uses the Android's Dream Service as a screen saver of sorts - it displays a slideshow of images. These images are housed in binary format within a database and decoded. I realize this is not the best way, but given the particular structure and purpose of this application, it is the most realistic. Additionally, the class does not make constant trips to database nor continuously decode image - it does this when it starts and then closes the resources.

With that being said, after the screen saver has run for a while, I occasionally receive an "Application has Stopped Working" message which I believe is related to an out of memory error. I find this a little odd because, far as I am aware, the bitmaps are only decoded once - when the service is attached to window. I do not see why there would be issues with memory when the only repetitive action is loading a bitmap into an ImageView container, certainly not something I believe requires a great deal of resources. I have looked over my code and have been unable to locate the issue.

What am I doing wrong; how can I stop these errors from occurring?

```
public class screenSaver extends DreamService {

    XmlPullParser parser;
    String storeImages = "";

    // creates messages

    public Bitmap drawText(Context c, int resource, String text) {

        Resources resources = c.getResources();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resource);
        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config config = bitmap.getConfig();
        if (config == null) {
            config = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        }
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(config, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(48 * scale);

        int textWidth = canvas.getWidth() - (int) (16 * scale);
        StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1f, 0f, false);

        int textHeight = textLayout.getHeight();
        float x = (bitmap.getWidth() - textWidth) / 2;
        float y = (bitmap.getHeight() - textHeight) / 2;

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(x, y);

        textLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        return bitmap;
    }

    ArrayList<Bitmap> imageList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    int slideCounter = 0;
    ImageView slide;
    Cursor images;
    Cursor corpImages;
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    private int counter = 0;

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            slide.setImageBitmap(imageList.get(counter));
            if (counter == (imageList.size() - 1)) {
                counter = 0;

            } else {
                counter++;

            }

        }
    };

    public screenSaver() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        setInteractive(false);
        setFullscreen(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen_saver);

        databaseHelper dbHelper = new databaseHelper(this);
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(this, lockActivity.class);
        testIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(testIntent); // unpin screen so screen saver can load
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("config", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String store = preferences.getString("store", "");

        String managerMessageText = "";
        String mainMessageText = "";
        String districtMessageText = "";
        try {


            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(this.getFilesDir(), "stores.xml"));
            parser = Xml.newPullParser();

            parser.setInput(input, null);

            // begin search for correct 'store' tag
            boolean elementsRemain = true;
            while (elementsRemain) {
                parser.next();
                int event = parser.getEventType();
                switch (event) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        String name = parser.getName();

                        if (name.equals("store")) {
                            Log.i("Screen Saver", "entering if store");
                            String number = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "number");
                            if (number.equals(store)) {

                                // located corresponding store, beginning parsing to find associate images and messages

                                boolean withinStore = true;
                                while (withinStore) {
                                    parser.next();

                                    if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                                        String tag = parser.getName();
                                        if (tag.equals("images")) {
                                            parser.nextTag();

                                            while (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("image")) {
                                                if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "id") != null && (!parser.getAttributeValue(null, "id").equals(""))) {
                                                    storeImages += parser.getAttributeValue(null, "id") + ",";
                                                }


                                                parser.nextTag();
                                                if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                                                    parser.nextTag();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        parser.next();

                                        if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                                            switch (tag) {

                                                case "message":
                                                    managerMessageText += parser.getText();
                                                    break;
                                                case "district":
                                                    districtMessageText += parser.getText();
                                                    break;
                                                case "corporate":
                                                    mainMessageText += parser.getText();
                                                    break;
                                                default:
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getName().equals("store")) {
                                        withinStore = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                parser.next();
                            }
                        } else {

                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT:
                        elementsRemain = false;
                        break;


                }


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error reading XML ", " " + e.getMessage());
        }

/*     LTO images
   try {
            File managerFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), store + ".txt");
            File universalFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "universal.txt");
            File districtFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "district.txt");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(managerFile));
            managerMessageText = reader.readLine();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(universalFile));
            mainMessageText = reader.readLine();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(districtFile));
            districtMessageText = reader.readLine();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error opening file: ", e.getMessage());
        }*/


       /*  images = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + databaseHelper.IMAGE + " FROM " + databaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " where " + databaseHelper.LTO + " = 1", null);
        images.moveToFirst();

        while(!images.isAfterLast()) {
            imageList.add(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(images.getBlob(images.getColumnIndex(databaseHelper.IMAGE)), 0, images.getBlob(images.getColumnIndex(databaseHelper.IMAGE)).length ));
            images.moveToNext();
        }
        images.close(); */


        if (storeImages.length() > 1) {
            storeImages = storeImages.substring(0, storeImages.length() - 1); // remove trailing comma
        }


        // get all images that are associated with store

        corpImages = db.rawQuery("SELECT  " + databaseHelper.SLIDE_IMAGE + " FROM " + databaseHelper.SLIDE_TABLE + " WHERE " + databaseHelper.SLIDE_ID + " IN (" + storeImages + ")", null);
        corpImages.moveToFirst();
        while (!corpImages.isAfterLast()) {
            imageList.add(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(corpImages.getBlob(corpImages.getColumnIndex(databaseHelper.SLIDE_IMAGE)), 0, corpImages.getBlob(corpImages.getColumnIndex(databaseHelper.SLIDE_IMAGE)).length));
            corpImages.moveToNext();
        }
        corpImages.close();
        db.close();

        // begin drawing message bitmaps

        if (managerMessageText != "") {
            imageList.add(drawText(this, R.drawable.message_background, "Manager Message: \n" + managerMessageText));
        }
        if (mainMessageText != "") {
            imageList.add(drawText(this, R.drawable.message_background, "Corporate Message: \n" + mainMessageText));
        }
        if (districtMessageText != "") {
            imageList.add(drawText(this, R.drawable.message_background, "District Manager Message: \n" + districtMessageText));
        }


        slide = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slider);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                updateGUI();

            }
        }, 0, 8000);

    }

    ;

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();

        // unpin screen so it can update
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(this, lockActivity.class);
        testIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(testIntent); // unpin screen so it can update
    }


    private void updateGUI() {
        if (reminder.running || hourlyReminder.running) {

            this.finish();
        } else {
            handler.post(runnable);

        }
    }


}
```

Thanks so much for any guidance.

Comment: I am quite certain this is a problem with Bitmap loading. Try reading [this](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using the decodeResource() method directly attempts to allocate memory for the constructed bitmap & can result OutOfMemory. There are several options to decode bitmaps efficiently.

Setting inJustDecodeBounds of BitmapFactory.Options to true avoids memory allocation in decoding step. It seems you are not using this option.

You don't need to load a full image/bitmap into memory when you just need to show a scaled down/smaller version of it. You can control this by setting inSampleSize of BitmapFactory.Options. It seems you are not using this option as well.

Try using:

```
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
```

etc. options while decoding bitmaps to efficiently handle the memory.

You can find a whole tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html